# Как в ASP.NET Core MVC сделать подгрузку ответа на введеный текст юзером?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="..." class="control-label"></label>
   <input asp-for="..." value="@ViewBag.User.Text" class="form-control" id="Text" />
   <input type="button" id="check" value="Check" class="btn btn-secondary" />
   <span asp-validation-for="..." class="text-danger" id="res"></span>
</div>
```

Как правильно в ASP.NET Core под MVC подгружать результат в span по id 'res' когда пользователь вводит текст в текстовом поле под id 'Text'? Мне нужна именно подгрузка во время ввода, а не автокмоплит или по нажатию кнопки.
Вот сам метод который нужно вызывать:

```
[Route("checktext/{username}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TextSearch(string text)
{
     bool Text= await AccountService.GeText(text);
     if(Text)
     {
         return new JsonResult("Доступний");
     }
     else
     {
         return new JsonResult("Не доступний");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чуть подправляем код контроллера:

```
[Route("checktext/{username}")]
public async Task<string> TextSearch(string username)
{
    bool Text = await AccountService.GeText(username);
```

Подписываем поле ввода на события и посылаем get-запрос с помощью ajax:

```
$('#Text').on('change keyup paste', function () {

    var text = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "checktext/" + text,

        success: function (response) {
            $('#res').text(response);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            $('#res').text("Error: " + err.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: не подскажите? Вопрос очень тупой, но я его должен задать: это серверная часть кода или он будет доступен пользователю?

Comment: @Yarik08 - Пользователь может посмотреть html-код страницы со всеми стилями и скриптами (правый клик в браузере - View Page Source). Так что опытному юзеру он доступен.