# Как при нажатии на кнопку и не обновляя страницу получить данные из базы и отобразить его на input type=text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Я хочу сделать так: при нажатии на кнопку, не обновляя страницу получить данные из базы данных и автоматически отобразить на двух input type=text, то есть у нас есть 3 input type=text и один button, при наборе id на первый input и нажатии на кнопку автоматам должен заполнить два других input, НЕ ОБНОВЛЯЯ СТРАНИЦУ! Заранее спасибо:=)

Comment: Кнопку подписываем на событие click и посылаем ajax-запрос в контроллер. Получаем в ответ данные и вставляем в текстбоксы. Делайте по аналогии: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009632/184217

Answer (score 0):

Создай на сервере apicontroller для данной задачи Используй post или get запрос в js,вуаля

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]